# Input array validation message error Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to show a custom validation message with array inputs when one of them doesn't pass the validation succesfully since the error that Laravel shows by default is something like this:

> The format of link.1 is invalid.

And I want to show something like this:

> The format of 'value' is invalid.

I read that there's this method called `messages()` which I can override in the Request file:

`BannerRequest.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class BannerRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "imagenes.*"        =>      "nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:5120",
            "links.*"           =>      "nullable|string|max:191|url",
            "idiomas.*"         =>      "required|string|max:191",
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */

    public function messages()
    {
        $messages = array();
        foreach($this->imagenes as $key => $valor) {
            $messages[] = array('imagenes.'.$key.'.mimes:jpeg,png,jpg' => "La imagen ".$valor." no contiene un formato válido");
            $messages[] = array('imagenes.'.$key.'.max:5120' => "La imagen ".$valor." no contiene un formato válido");

        }

        foreach($this->links as $key => $valor) {
            $messages[] = array('links.'.$key.'.url' => "El link ".$valor." no es una URL válida");

        }

        return $messages;
    }
}
```

According to documentation:

> This method should return an array of attribute / rule pairs and their
>   corresponding error messages

So, since I'm handling array of inputs I thought I should iterate over them in order to get their key to get something like this: `link.0.validation_rule` then `link.1.validation_rule` and so on...

But if I do this, when displaying the errors, I get the following error on my view:

`Array to string conversion`

The error is thrown on `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.php` at `line 247`.

What am I doing wrong?, since Laravel doesn't mention a lot for validating input arrays.

Comment: Does your validation works as expected ?

Comment: @TharakaDilshan Yes, if I erase the `messages()` overriden method, it works well, but I don't want Laravel to show the default message it uses when receiving an array of inputs, I want to change that message so that it doesn't appear as for example: `The format of link.1 is invalid.` instead I want something like `The format of 'value_submitted' is invalid.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, the `messages()` method should return an array of messages as follows:

```
    public function messages()
    {
        $messages = array();
        foreach($this->imagenes as $key => $valor) {
            $messages['imagenes.'.$key.'.mimes:jpeg,png,jpg'] = "La imagen ".$valor." no contiene un formato válido";
            $messages['imagenes.'.$key.'.max:5120'] = "La imagen ".$valor." no contiene un formato válido";


        }

        foreach($this->links as $key => $valor) {
            $messages['links.'.$key.'.url'] =  "El link ".$valor." no es una URL válida";

        }

        return $messages;
    }
```

I hope this can be helpful to other people that have this same doubt, since most of similar questions here don't have a concise answer. If there's a better answer for this or a cleaner way if it exists of doing this, I would be glad to read it.